# For any real sequence converging to $0$ , is there a $2\pi$ periodic continuous function whose Fourier coefficients are larger than the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n \to 0$ as $|n| \to \infty$ . Does there exist a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that $|\hat f(n)| \ge a_n , \forall n \in \mathbb Z$  ? Or at least , does there exist a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that $|\hat f(n)| \ge a_n$ , for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb Z$ ?

Here $\hat f(n):=\dfrac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)e^{-inx} dx$

Comment: $C([-\pi,\pi]) \subset L^2([-\pi,\pi])$

Comment: @DanielFischer : Yes ... but how does that help ?

Comment: If you only ask $|\hat{f}(n)| > a_n$ occasionnally then simply choose $n_j$ such that $\sum_j |a_{n_j}|$ converges. Fourier series with large coefficients are distributions, for example $\hat{f}(n) = 1$ gives $f(x) = 2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x+2\pi k)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{inx}$ the periodic Dirac delta.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I understand your comment . such $f$ does not exist if $\sum|a_n|^2$ diverges

Comment: @reuns : your function $f$ is not even well defined ; let alone continuous ...

Comment: @misao That's what I explained $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{inx}$ is not a function but a distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer noted, the inequality $|\hat f(n)|\ge a_n$ cannot hold for all $n$ if $(a_n)$ is not square-summable, since $\sum |\hat f(n)|^2<\infty$ for every function in $L^2([0,2\pi])$, in particular for every continuous function on $[0,2\pi]$.

But, as reuns said, it's possible to find continuous $f$ such that $|\hat f(n)|\ge a_n$ infinitely often. Indeed, there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $|a_{n_k}|\le 2^{-k}$ for every $k$. Let 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k} a_{n_k}\exp(n_k i x)
$$
By the Weierstrass M-test, the series converges uniformly, hence $f$ is continuous. It has the desired Fourier coefficients by construction.

Comment: (for every $L^2([0,T])$ function)